# How does über recognize what friend invited a specific user?

Tags: ios

How does über recognize what friend invited a specific user without using email or phone number?

I understand the link has a user id at the end of the URL and then that site redirects to the apple app store but what data is über collecting when a user opens the link in safari before sending the user to app store url scheme?

- Safari cookies aren't accessible from the app, right?
- Also I don't believe they don't use what email/phone number you invited because they also allow you to share on twitter which would require the user to register via/connect their twitter account right?